# Prove $f(x)=g(x)$ has at least 1 solution $c$ in $(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $f$ and $g$ are two continuous functions from $[a,b]$ to real numbers s.t $f(a)\lt g(a)$ and $f(b)\gt g(b)$. Prove that $f(x)=g(x)$ has at least 1 solution $c$ in $(a,b)$.

I tried using intermediate value theorem. It states that if f continuous on [a,b] f(a)< d< f(b) then there exists a point c in (a,b) such that f(c)=d

Comment: See also: [Proving that $f(x) = g(x)$ for some $x \in [a,b]$ if $f,g$ continuous, $f(a) < g(a)$ and $f(b) > g(b)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/348363)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part $(a)$, let $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$.  Notice the conditions imply that $h(a)<0$ and $h(b)>0$.  Since $h$ is continuous, the intermediate value theorem gives us some $c$ in $(a,b)$ where $h(c)=0$.  See if you can finish the rest!