# Proving that $f(x) = g(x)$ for some $x \in [a,b]$ if $f,g$ continuous, $f(a) < g(a)$ and $f(b) > g(b)$

Tags: continuity

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$ and that $f(a) < g(a)$ but $f(b) > g(b)$.
>   Prove that $f(x) = g(x)$ for some $x \in [a,b]$.

---

I did try and actually did get as far as coming up with $f-g$. Would I set $h(x)= f(x)- g(x)$ and say $h(a) <x< h(b)$?

Comment: I did try and actually did get as far as coming up with f-g. Would i set h(x)= f(x)- G(x) and say H(a) <x< H(b)?

Comment: For $H=f-g$, you have $H(a)<0$ and $H(b)>0$. Then $H(a)<0<H(b)$. Since $H$ is continuous  ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hint: Apply the Intermediate Value Theorem to the function $f-g$ on the interval $[a,b]$.