# If $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$, $f(a) \le g(a)$, and $g(b) \le f(b)$, prove there is a $c$ in $[a,b]$ with $f(c)$ $=$ $g(c)$.

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$, $f(a)$ $\le$ $g(a)$, and $g(b)$ $\le$ $f(b)$, prove there is a point $c$ $\in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)$ $=$ $g(c)$.

Any ideas on how to solve?

I think I have to use the Intermediate Value Thm but I'm not sure.

Comment: You probably meant $g(b)\le f(b)$. In this case, consider the function $f-g$.

Comment: Yes you are correct

Comment: Then change your question's data, @Carl

Comment: See also: [Proving that $f(x) = g(x)$ for some $x \in [a,b]$ if $f,g$ continuous, $f(a) < g(a)$ and $f(b) > g(b)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/348363)

Comment: Consider f-g..................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Try to construct a function $h$ from $f$ and $g$ with the properties:
$$h(a) \leq 0$$
$$h(b) \geq 0$$
$$h(x)=0\iff f(x)=g(x)$$

Then, what does the intermediate value theorem tell you about $h$?

Comment: "$h(x) = 0 \iff f(a) = f(b)$"?! I don't understand what you're trying to say there.

Comment: @kahen Me neither. I was writting in a hurry. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** If you can't use the intermediate value theorem, try to find $\sup_x f(x)-g(x) >0$ and apply continuity there.