# Apply the intermediate value theorem to the intersection of two functions

Tags: calculus

Prove the following using the intermediate value theorem:

$f$, $g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$, $f(a)< g(a)$ but $f(b) >g(b)$

Prove: $f(c)=g(c)$ for some $c \in (a,b)$

I am not sure if i am correct:

- $g$ is continuous: using IVT $g(c)=j$,   $g(a)< j <g(b)$  , c belongs to (a,b)

  - $f$ is continuous: using IVT $f(c)=k$,   $f(a)< k < f(b)$ ,
    therefore by the given inequality: $f(a)< j <f(b)$
    Hence, by IVT $j= f(c)= g(c)$

Comment: Take a peek at the function $\;h(x):=f(x)-g(x)\;$ ...

Comment: g is continuous: using IVT g(c)=l   g(a)<j<g(b j belongs to (a,b)
f is continuous: using IVT f(c)=k   f(a)< k < f(b) , k belongs to (a,b)

Therefore by the given inequality: f(a)< j <f(b)
Hence,by IVT j= f(c)= g(c) Is this way correct?

Comment: No: it doesn't seem to be correct: where do you think you proved the existence of a point where both functions $\;f,g\;$ have the same value?

Comment: By the given inequality it can be shown that j lies between f(a) and f(b) , and since it lies between them by the intermediate value theorem it can be shown that j= f(c) ?

Comment: I really can't see it clrealy, @user...did you try the idea in my first comment?

Comment: ya I did try that. could not prove it.

Comment: if we can show that j lies between f(a) and f(b) is it correct to conclude that j= f(C)?

Comment: See also: [Proving that $f(x) = g(x)$ for some $x \in [a,b]$ if $f,g$ continuous, $f(a) < g(a)$ and $f(b) > g(b)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/348363)

Answer (score 2):

Following my coment:

$$h(x):=f(x)-g(x)\implies \begin{cases}h(a)=f(a)-g(a)<0\\{}\\
h(b)=f(b)-g(b)>0\end{cases}$$

Since $\;h\;$ is continuous, the IVT tells us there exists...(complete)

Comment: @user146656, you begin your coment with "using IVT g(c)=l g(a)<j<g(b j belongs to (a,b)" . I can't see here how "j" relates to "c" or to "l" ...and you should *really* try to learn a basic MathJax to write properly mathematics in this site: that'll help **a lot** to the understanding. Try here:http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I have edited the question. That was just a typing mistake.

Comment: Do you think it is, @user146656 ? I really can't even make much sense of it...how miraculously do we get $\;j=f(c)\;$?? This would mean $\;k=j\;$ , according to your notation...