# Suppose f and g are continuous on [a, b] and that f(a) < g(a), but f(b) > g(b). Prove that f(x) = g(x) for some x in [a, b].

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-writing

I have been asked to prove the following question for my Real Analysis course, and I'm not quite sure how to go about proving this. The textbook is Spivak's *Calculus*, and this is question 10 from Chapter 7. Thank you in advance!

Suppose $f,g$ are continuous on $[a, b]$ and that $f(a) < g(a)$, but $f(b) > g(b)$. Prove that $f(x) = g(x)$ for some $x$ in $[a, b]$.

My idea is that this problem will involve the intermediate value theorem, as $f$ holds values both less than and greater than $g$ for some $x$.

Comment: Do you know intermediate value theorem?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of: [Proving that $f(x) = g(x)$ for some $x \in [a,b]$ if $f,g$ continuous, $f(a) < g(a)$ and $f(b) > g(b)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/348363)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h=f-g$, $h(a)<0, h(b)>0$, the intermediate value theorem implies that  there exists $x\in [a,b]$ with $h(x)=0$.

Comment: Beautiful, I get it. Thank you much!!